# How to handle dynamic changing ID's In XPath?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate login into a website.
The id of email box changes each time I search for the page

For example:

```
//*[@id="undefined-undefined-E-mail-53172"]
```

When I refresh the page:

```
//*[@id="undefined-undefined-E-mail-33458"]
```

So I have to change the code each time like:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("undefined-undefined-E-mail-53172").send_keys("X@gmail.com")

driver.find_element_by_id("undefined-undefined-E-mail-33458").send_keys("X@gmail.com")
```

And when I refresh again, it doesn't work.

Comment: By actually using the xpath, and not finding by id. Provide your sample html for an answer.

Comment: Link : 
chrome-extension://megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig/views.html?view=onBoarding

-> Start tour
-> Skip presentation

Then u'ill find email box

Comment: Xpath is changing too .
//*[@id="undefined-E-mail-undefined-52987"] Then
//*[@id="undefined-E-mail-undefined-33458"] Then
//*[@id="undefined-E-mail-undefined-64853"] ...

Comment: the view looks like a pop up. Can you do `driver.switch_to().alert()` and then try entering the email.

Answer (score 1):

To handle dynamic element induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable()` 
since ID is dynamic use `starts-with()` xpath expression.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[starts-with(@id,'undefined-undefined-E-mail-')]"))).send_keys("X@gmail.com")
```

Or

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[starts-with(@id,'undefined-undefined-E-mail-')]"))).send_keys("X@gmail.com")
```

**Note:**  You need following imports to execute above code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I just tried it but still nothing . What does " WebDriverWait(driver,20) " the 20 stands for ?

Comment: It will wait upto 20 seconds before throw any exception.can you share your url?

Comment: here is the error : 
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[starts-with(@id,'undefined-E-mail-undefined-')]"))).send_keys("X@gmail.com")
  File "C:\Users\Salma\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: In that case check any iframe is there? or share me your url ?

Comment: For the link : You have to download this chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-free-multi-log/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig?hl=fr

Comment: Then enter this link : chrome-extension://megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig/views.html?view=onBoarding -> Start tour -> Skip presentation Then u'ill find email box

Comment: Sorry I can't download any extension.I am working on corporate laptop.

Comment: If you can download the extension "only .crx file" on your desktop 
i'll send you my whole code.
The extension will be executed only in the run browser

Comment: How can i check which iframe there ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this it will work

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//*[contains(@id,'undefined-undefined-E-mail')]").sendKeys("aa@yyy.com");
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'undefined-undefined-E-mail')]").sendKeys("aa@yyy.com");
```

Comment: Error : driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'undefined-E-mail-undefined')]").send_keys("aa@yyy.com") 

File "C:/Users/Hamza/PycharmProjects/test/Chromedone.py", line 32, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id,'undefined-E-mail-undefined')]").send_keys("aa@yyy.com")
  File "C:\Users\Hamza\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Hamza\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Hamza\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\Hamza\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id,'undefined-E-mail-undefined')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: try using the second xpath

Comment: if that also didnt worked means check whether they are in iframes or not

Comment: if you have a chance to use sikuli you can use it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it 2 ways:

1/ check if somekinda element contains something ( like part of a string, which someone has already answered in a different answer ... )

2/ The one that I use -> using a full Xpath. Here is how you do that:

- Download this ( or something like ) this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl
- Go to the website and copy xpath ... when you get xpath that contains a specific ID ( example: `//*[@id="5633040"]/div/input` , you will just go above that ID and you will try to create a static XPath ( thats what is this extension good for ) .. `//*[@id="app_content"]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div` <- lets say this is above that `//*[@id="5633040"]`
- so if you put something like this in your xpath search, you should get the same result as with dynamic one `//*[@id="app_content"]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div/input` or this one if there is more divs `//*[@id="app_content"]/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div/div[number]/div/input`

P.S -> if you cant install extensions, you will just have to try to see if you typed it right and it works

~ Hope it helps :)